# PyCharm won't install gym package

Tags: python, module, pip, pycharm, openai-gym

I just installed it with pip, and wanted to import it in PyCharm, but got an error:

---

Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- gym

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

---

does anyone know how to fix this by any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From pycharm,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for `gym` python package.

Then click on `Install package` to install the `gym` package

Comment: now it says "error.DependencyNotInstalled("{}. (HINT: you can install Atari dependencies by running 'pip install gym[atari]'.)".format(e))
gym.error.DependencyNotInstalled: No module named 'atari_py'. (HINT: you can install Atari dependencies by running 'pip install gym[atari]'.)"

Comment: and i already installed Atari :( running pip install says it's already there

Comment: Ok. When you navigate to `settings` -> `project Interpreter` you will see all the installed packages in the venv which you have selected. If the dependencies are listed in the table then no need to install those. Otherwise you need to install `atari` using the process mentioned above

Comment: it's throwing an error :( https://imgur.com/a/5fpgvLl and I checked and i have cython, make, and cmake installed also